# Finding $a_n$ from recurrence relation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to find the closed from for $a_n$ as part of a series solution for an ODE, where the recurrence relation is given by
 $$a_n=-\frac{a_{n-2}}{n(n-3)}$$

I have come up with $a_{2n}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}a_0}{4n(n-1)(2n-3)!}$, but the correct answer is listed as $a_{2n}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)}{(2n)!}$. Is it possible that these are somehow equivalent? If not, how can I derive the correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
(2n)!=2n\cdot(2n-1)\cdot(2n-2)\cdot(2n-3)!=4n(n-1)(2n-3)!\cdot\mathbf{(2n-1)},
$$
hence, if $a_0=1$, your answer and the suggested one coincide.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Thank you!